# How can i delete my token?

Tags: token, delete

i have a token:
https://solscan.io/token/TR1S2n2dFGQEAAUcttLTE5zNdiSW96QA51Bb4PSnWae#txs

But i want delete. "TR1S2n2dFGQEAAUcttLTE5zNdiSW96QA51Bb4PSnWae"
beacuse i have 0.38 sol in this account and i would like get back.

when i currently try

> solana transfer GneATQZbye3W6DrFg5D1MQmr7mAMC3wyVGbq31oePaug 0.38

i got an error message:

```
Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees
```

anybody have solution to my problem?

**tahnk you!**

Answer (score 1):

If this is/was a token account, it sounds like you want to close the account to recover your rent fees. Without code, some wallets (I believe SolFlare) offer the ability to close accounts to recover your rent.